# QGIS: use geometry from different layer in symbology expression

Tags: qgis, symbology, z-value

I have a project with multiple layers.
The purple dots are from a pointfile with the symbology-expression:
`z($geometry)> '14.5'`. (so it only displays a purple dot when the Z-value is more than 14.5m).

I have a second layer with polygons, visible as the partly-transparent arc-area in red.

The next step i want to make in my project is to:
have the purple dots appear only if:
z($geometry)>'14.5' AND
the x-y of that spot is within the geographical extent of the polygon from the second layer

What step do i have to take to get this done.

[image: example without last step]

Answer (score 8):

Your question is very similar to what I've done [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ANINvQGK9cg) recently.

I used expression:

```
if(
within($geometry,geometry(get_feature(layer,attribute,value))),
result_when_true,
result_when_false
)
```

In your case step 1: **filter data table by**

```
z($geometry)> '14.5'
```

step 2: **paste expression in point symbology layer (see gif to find where)**

```
if(
within($geometry,geometry(get_feature('your_polygon_layer_name','the_layers_field','feature_data'))),
1,
0
)
```

You can use the same expression for labels but must change *1* and *0* values to "*label_field_name*" and to *null*.

That's it.

[image]

Comment: Good answer! Would it work to drop the if-part completely and just use `within(...)`?

Comment: Nope it wouldn't.

Comment: That's surprising... Did you try?

Comment: Is it possible that this doesn' t work in rule-based symbology? I can get it work in a test environment, but not in my project. I used
if(
within($geometry,geometry(get_feature('bronpolygonen_4a087198_dafa_4185_a358_d410ed1a980e','TYPECTRL','MONITOR HOOFD VERLICHT'))),
1,
0
)

Comment: Or is it possible that my dataset is just to big (626000 features)?

Comment: @CaptainAhab I don't know if that is a reason, try to use get_feature_by_id('layer','feature_id') as an another option.

Comment: Ik couldn’t get this to work so I installed RefFunctions with geomwithin.